# Updating sufficient statistics parameter sets in Bayesian Inference (Changepoint Detection)

Tags: bayesian, inference, change-point, sufficient-statistics, anomaly-detection

I am trying to implement and customize a changepoint detection method based on Bayesian Inference (referring to https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3742v1.pdf). Now I struggle understanding the conjugate prior choice and its corresponding update parameters (step 1 and 8 in the image below).
I do understand the basic idea behind the concept of sufficient statistics but what I don't understand is how to set the prior and its parameters properly (or where to get information about these).

[image: Pseudocode of the paper linked above, all rights to their respective owners.]

[Pseudocode of the paper linked above, all rights to their respective owners.]

---

Let's say I want to use a conjugate prior based on the log-normal distribution, is there any book/literature/source where I can get information about how to set the update parameter sets?